# Javascript : show latitude and longitude on mouse click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I'm using javascript to show the current location of a user on a map. I need to add a listener on map click to show latitude and longtitude.
this is my code, it doesn't work i know that i'm doing something wrong
could you please help me figure out whats wrong:

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
            );
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                title: "Your current location!"
            });

        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }

    function setUpClickListener(map) {
        // Attach an event listener to map display
        // obtain the coordinates and display in an alert box.
        map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
            var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
                evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
            alert('Clicked at ' + Math.abs(coord.lat.toFixed(4)) +
                ((coord.lat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S') +
                ' ' + Math.abs(coord.lng.toFixed(4)) +
                ((coord.lng > 0) ? 'E' : 'W'));
        });
    }

    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    setUpClickListener(map);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #mapContainer
    {
        height: 500px;
        width: 800px;
        border: 10px solid #eaeaea;
    }
</style>
<div id="mapContainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`coord.lat` is a function. To get the latitude and the longitude you need to write `coord.lat(). toFixed(4)`

Answer (score 0):

'tap' event is not available in google maps [Evenets](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Try using:

```
map.addListener('click', function(evt) {
  var lat = evt.latLng.lat();
  var lng = evt.latLng.lng();
  // ... Do what you want with the lat and lng here....
});
```